# Fade in/out dynamically included content

Tags: php, dynamic, include, fade

I have website that uses PHP to dynamically include content of the site.
The PHP looks like this:

```
<div id="content">
        <?php
        $content = $_GET['content'];
        $pages = array('forside', 'menukort', 'hvemervi', 'Kontakt', 'catering');
            if (!empty($content)) {
                if(in_array($content, $pages)) {
                $content .= '.php';
                include($content);
            } else {
                    echo'Siden kunne ikke findes. Der må være sket en fejl! Gå tilbage til <a href="index.php">forsiden</a>';
                }

            } else {
                   include('forside.php');
            }   
        ?>
</div>
```

TRying some Jquery

> $(document).ready(function() {
>       $('#menu-bar a').click(function(e) {
>           e.preventDefault(); // we'll get the pages via ajax.

```
    var url = $(this).attr('href'); // use href as url to loag

    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        success: function(data) {

            // when ajax is done, fade old content out
            $('#content').fadeOut('slow', function() {

                $(this).html(data); // replace contents

                // fade new content in
                $(this).fadeIn('slow');
            });
        }
    });
});
```

});​​​​

What should i do to fade in/out the content of the side when when `$content` is include?

Comment: "Fading" is generally a client-side thing, requiring something like javascript.  You might look into jQuery.

Comment: @Jedwards I'm updating post with my java script, can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Can you include you whole HTML file, give a little context or create a jsfiddle of it?

Comment: @Tim.baker 
There is really no other content on the site at the moment except for a header, menu, and a footer positioned in <div> in this order: 
Wrapper > Header - Menu > content > footer

Comment: Headers and such are statically inclcluded with php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The HTML of your page is being written synchronously by PHP.  If you want to fade in particular chunks of content when they become available, you'll want to deliver the frame of your page, and then use JS and AJAX on the front end to load content at runtime and fade it in.

**Edit After JS was Provided**

The PHP that you have provided has an extra else statement and unpaired curly braces.  Perhaps it is erroring and that is why your JS is not pulling the content properly.  However, your basic approach seems sound.

I should note, also, that running include() on user provided data seems like a pretty big security hole.

Comment: Isn't that what my script is doing. 
For what I understand, it grabs the url of the site, fades out the old content, fetches new content, and fades it in? 
Isn't that basically what you're trying to make me do? 
In that case, could you help correct the code, i guess I'm not grabbing the URL properbly.

Comment: Sorry, when my answer was written, you hadn't included any javascript in your question.

Comment: Thanks for your edit, i will check out the else statement! 
Also, for your include() the thing is, there's no db on that site, and it wont have any. I'm paid like 50 bucks for it, for a friend - So it's basically just slamming his free wix.com site into a proper site.